# How can I figure out the dimensions for a shrink band from these measurements?

Tags: packaging

Hi my graphic designer is working on custom logo and mockup for my ice cream lid. The company I am buying ice cream pints and lids from doesn't sell shrink bands with the items, so i have to go to a different site to get those. The shrink band site has A lot of different sizes so I'm not sure which one will fit my products.

Any idea how I can figure out the proper dimensions for a shrink band from the photo? The measurements are in inches.

[image: Photo of lid dimensions]

The site I'm trying to get the shrink bands from says to use this formula to find the dimensions but this is where I get confused:

[image: Site description how to find measurements]

Comment: It would be a good idea to post a photo of your tub, so we can see what we're dealing with.  In the UK, we have tubs that come up to a lip where the lid is, the lid sitting in a grove that runs round the top of this lip.

Answer (score 2):

This is much more a "basic math" question, than a graphic design one.

You simply need the circumference of a circle, given its diameter. The formula is C = πd, so circumference of your band equals roughly **12.742** (3.14 * 4.0709) inches.

The height of your band is up to you, but probably taller than your lid (which seems a bit taller than 0.65 inches)